# Databinding WPF Repository and Model

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ado.net-entity-data-model

I´ve got a ADO.Net Entity Data Model that contains a table called `DJ`.

I want to bind the Name-column of the database to a listbox in my WPF application. My problem is, that I don´t want any code in the code-behind file.

Do I need a Model-Class for that? How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need code behind, but it is highly recommended to have a ViewModel. Your view should not listen to the model directly. It may seem simple in the beginning, but as your application grows, you will need to do validation, aggregation, hiding some model part ect... and that should be part of your ViewModel, not your Model or view.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I planed to make a ViewModel in my application, but don´t know how exactly I have to handle my Ado Entities. Do you have any Code/Examples/Links?

Comment: Here are some examples from MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752057.aspx 
and good article from CodeProject : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TwoWayDataBinding.aspx